# webview после обновления chrome до 79 версии не может получить доступ к камере

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, chromium

После обновления Chrome до 79 версии 18 декабря 2019 веб-форма перестала получать доступ к камере и микрофону устройства.
На версиях 78 и 56 всё работает. Может, кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и смог её решить?

в логи падает такая ошибка каждые 15 секунд

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
```

Код в активити

```
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            });
        }

    });

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);

    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

в манифесте есть все необходимые разрешения

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /> <!-- В результат слияния с манифестом HockeyApp'а требуется переопределить разрешения -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_LOCAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="true" />
```